# Mansion of Madness scenario game time

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I've played a handful of scenarios now for Mansions of Madness 2nd edition, but they all seem to take far longer than the "recommended" time in the app. And quite frankly, while I love the game, it just takes too long to get regular plays in.

What general suggestions do you have to complete scenarios in less time? (or at least closer to the time the app states)

Comment: Make sure you are only resolving ONE horror check per investigator for the monster with the highest horror rating and if multiple investigators need to do a horror check for the same monster, they do the same encounter, not a separate encounter each - we missed that the first few times we played and it made the game much longer than it needed to be

Comment: That's interesting, we DID do a seperate encounter each when resolving horror checks against the same monster.

Answer (score 2):

Once your party gets more used to the game, the time you take should get closer to the time the app states. It still varies strongly, but we usually fall within the designated timeframe by now, often with one "new player" and a bunch of veterans.